# what does "movl (%esi, %ecx, 4), eax" imply?

Tags: assembly, x86

What does it mean to have these 3 instructions as the source of a movl instruction?

```
(%esi, %ecx, 4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means:

Calculate Address = (ESI + ECX * 4). 
Read the value into EAX from 32-bit value at that memory address.

From the linked article:

> GAS instructions generally have the form: `mnemonic source, destination`.

See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax

Personally I prefer the more readable MASM syntax

```
mov EAX, dword ptr [ESI + ECX * 4]
     ^     ^
     |     +-- source in a readable syntax
     +-------- destination
```

Which has the form: `mnemonic destination, source` (exactly the other way round).

**Comment**
Oh and what you call instructions, are really `parameters`.
The instruction is the whole statement.

Comment: It's AT&T syntax, so it's actually the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the clear up.  Is the main difference between Intel and AT&T the order of source and destination in the instruction?

Comment: @tippenein mainly, yes. But there are other differences esp. related to the question you posted. See this link for more info: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: @tippenein In addition to the differences mentioned (operand order, addressing mode syntax), there are many differences in the instruction mnemonics (names), and, the mnemonics often have a suffix which declares the data type. For example, `movb`, `movw`, `movl` work on 8, 16, and 32 bit data respectively. There are also completely different mnemonics, such as `retf` (Intel) vs `lret` (AT&T).